# How to fall asleep when your mind is "not ready"

Tags: sleep, productivity

I have read a lot of tips on how to put yourself at peace before sleep, but they don't work for me (possibly because of keeping in mind that it's a problem I struggle to overcome).

I am fresh graduate, currently unemployed, trying to keep myself busy every day. Before bedtime, I seem to be unable to stop my mind from planning, thinking etc. I get a lot of ideas and I cannot wait for another day.

Any suggestions on how to keep myself content and calm before bedtime?

Comment: Do some research and reword your questions in the form "I have heard X, Y and/or Z can help falling asleep,[insert link to evidence here] is this true?"

Comment: @daskas What have you tried so far? Some melatonin or something similar? It sounds like a mental health issue. You may also ask at 
[Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/) site. I would suggest, take the notes of your ideas before going to sleep and try again.